# How to convert Numpy Array to Python Dictionary with Sequential Keys?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have a matrix in the form of a numpy array like this :

```
myarray = np.array[[0,400,405,411,415,417,418,0]
                   [0,404,412,419,423,422,422,0]
                   [0,409,416,421,424,425,425,0]
                   [0,411,414,417,420,423,426,0]
                   [0,409,410,410,413,419,424,0]
                   [0,405,404,404,409,414,419,0]]
```

and also empty dictionary :

```
dict = { }
```

In my case, i want to convert that array to python dictionary where the keys of dictionary are sequential number calculated from up-left value (`myarray[0][0]`) until bottom-right value (`myarray[5][7]`) interleaved by row.
So the result will be like this :

```
dict = { 1 : 0, 2 : 400, 3: 405, ........, 47 : 419 ,48 : 0 }
```

is there any solution for this condition?
wish for your help.. Any help would be very appreciated..

Comment: Flatten it and `zip` it with `numpy.arange()`, pass the zipped structure to `dict()`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `flatten` and then create the dictionary with the help of `enumerate` starting from 1:

```
myarray = np.array([[0,400,405,411,415,417,418,0],
                   [0,404,412,419,423,422,422,0],
                   [0,409,416,421,424,425,425,0],
                   [0,411,414,417,420,423,426,0],
                   [0,409,410,410,413,419,424,0],
                   [0,405,404,404,409,414,419,0]])

d = dict(enumerate(myarray.flatten(), 1))
```

Output of `d`:

```
{1: 0,
 2: 400,
 3: 405,
 4: 411,
 5: 415,
 6: 417,
 7: 418,
 8: 0,
 9: 0,
 10: 404,
 ...
```